# RewriteRule Cause Slow Down

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have added a RewriteRule in my site

my site has its own routing.

Sample

```
http://site.com/home/task/processCity/cityName/NameOfCity/stateName/NameOfState
```

equivalent to

```
http://site.com/index.php?obj=home&task=processCity&cityName=NameOfCity&landingName=NameOfState
```

I tried to shortent the url to

```
http://site.com/NameOfCity/NameOfState
```

with the following code below

as i have notice.
this code makes the site load slow. or css and javascript are not working.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)? /index.php?obj=home&task=processCity&cityName=$1&stateName=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

and the original link is not working

```
http://site.com/home/task/processCity/cityName/NameOfCity/stateName/NameOfState
```

but when i use this one everything works fine also the original link is still working

```
RewriteRule ^find/(.*)/(.*)? /index.php?obj=home&task=processCity&cityName=$1&stateName=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

what could be the cause of the problem in the first RewriteRule? any way to fix this
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original link isn't working because your regex is not correct, without `$` it is matching and impacting your long URL as well. Change your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?obj=home&task=processCity&cityName=$1&stateName=$2 [QSA,L]
```